# root phpmyadmin with all privileges shows: "No privileges" and cannot create nor modify anything

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, root, privileges

I have installed Bitnami Wamp server it means: Apache 2 as Web Server, MySQL as SQL server, PHP and PhpMyAdmin. It runs on Wondows 10.

I have followed all steps in video tutorials:

user root couldn't Access PhpMyAdmin, but now it does because I changed the my.ini file and I wrote there:

```
skip-grant-tables
```

And then I could already enter PhpMyAdmin with 'root' user, but it shows always: **no privilege**

I have checked the users table and it shows like 'root' has all privileges.

I have changed the configuration file of PhpMyAdmin config.inc.php and set:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

And also as:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

like it is told in many forums in the internet and none of them Works.

I have tried the cmd console and there I may create and modify data bases but in PhpMyAdmin doesn't Work.

I don't find how to go further to solve this issue with PhpMyAdmin. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thank you very much in advance